# Why am I getting curl error 55: Failed sending data to peer when trying to send an email?

Tags: c++, email, curl

I used this template provided here to email myself using curl: https://www.phidgets.com/?view=articles&article=LIBCURLHowTo

It all worked fine in Linux; however, I'm trying to get it to work in Windows and I'm getting this console message:

```
curl_easy_perform() failed: Failed sending data to the peer

Process returned 55 (0x37)   execution time : 0.165 s
Press any key to continue.
```

My full code is as follows:

```
/*
 * SMTP example showing how to send e-mails
 *
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl\curl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>

/* This is a simple example showing how to send mail using libcurl's SMTP
 * capabilities. For an example of using the multi interface please see
 * smtp-multi.c.
 *
 * Note that this example requires libcurl 7.20.0 or above.
 */

#define FROM    "example@example.com"
#define TO      "example2@example.com"

static const char *payload_text[] = {
  "Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2010 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
  "To: " TO "(Steve)\r\n",
  "From: " FROM "(Me)\r\n",
  "Subject: hacked_system.txt has been deleted!\r\n",
  "\r\n", /* empty line to divide headers from body, see RFC5322 */
  "hacked_system.txt has been deleted from SteveOS!\r\n",
  NULL
};

struct upload_status {
  int lines_read;
};

static size_t payload_source(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
  struct upload_status *upload_ctx = (struct upload_status *)userp;
  const char *data;

  if((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size*nmemb) < 1)) {
    return 0;
  }

  data = payload_text[upload_ctx->lines_read];

  if(data) {
    size_t len = strlen(data);
    memcpy(ptr, data, len);
    upload_ctx->lines_read++;

    return len;
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(void)

{

   {mkdir("C:\\SteveOS");
   std::ofstream outfile ("C:\\SteveOS\\hacked_system.txt");
   DeleteFile  ("C:\\SteveOS\\hacked_system.txt");}

  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
  struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;
  struct upload_status upload_ctx;

  upload_ctx.lines_read = 0;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* This is the URL for your mailserver */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587");

    /* Note that this option isn't strictly required, omitting it will result
     * in libcurl sending the MAIL FROM command with empty sender data. All
     * autoresponses should have an empty reverse-path, and should be directed
     * to the address in the reverse-path which triggered them. Otherwise,
     * they could cause an endless loop. See RFC 5321 Section 4.5.5 for more
     * details.
     */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, FROM);

    /* Add two recipients, in this particular case they correspond to the
     * To: and Cc: addressees in the header, but they could be any kind of
     * recipient. */
    recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, TO);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);

    /* We're using a callback function to specify the payload (the headers and
     * body of the message). You could just use the CURLOPT_READDATA option to
     * specify a FILE pointer to read from. */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payload_source);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &upload_ctx);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "example@example.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL);

    /* Send the message */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* Free the list of recipients */
    curl_slist_free_all(recipients);

    /* curl won't send the QUIT command until you call cleanup, so you should
     * be able to re-use this connection for additional messages (setting
     * CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM and CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT as required, and calling
     * curl_easy_perform() again. It may not be a good idea to keep the
     * connection open for a very long time though (more than a few minutes
     * may result in the server timing out the connection), and you do want to
     * clean up in the end.
     */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  return (int)res;
}
```

The reason as to why the email reads that way is because this is a class assignment. Also, I was tasked with creating that hacked_system.txt file and deleting it. The file isn't deleting, though, so now my problem is two-fold. How would I delete the file?

The code that worked on Linux had had two email addresses, a to: and a cc:. I have removed the cc:, but I have not tested that on Linux. To send the email, I had used real email addresses of mine as from: and to:. Also, the password was a Google account app password that I have replaced with x's.

In place of DeleteFile, I had used the Boost libraries on Linux, but it was proving to be not worthwhile to build the libraries for Windows.

I'd greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Edit: Could it be because I don't have SSL integrated into libcurl?

Comment: I had compiled libcurl myself. I have just tried the Windows download by curl.haxx.se with OpenSSL, brotli, libssh2, nghttp2, and zlib integrated.

I now get: 

`curl_easy_perform() failed: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

Process returned 60 (0x3C)   execution time : 0.173 s
Press any key to continue.`

Comment: I got it to work! I used the CA certificate found here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html and I added these lines to my code: `static const char *pCACertFile = ("C:\\Users\\Steven\\Downloads\\Homework\\Homework2_3\\curl_ca\\cacert.pem");` and `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, pCACertFile);`

Now to figure out deleting hacked_system.txt!

Comment: I got it all working! There's no need for any more help! I ended up getting the Boost libraries set up and using the Boost filesystem library to delete hacked_system.txt. Now that I have more experience with all of this, it was easy for me to set up the Boost libraries.